# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

```
var options = {
  https.globalAgent.options.ca: [fs.readFileSync('')]
};
```

I am getting a syntax error when I execute the file.

Comment: Of course you do, because that's invalid syntax.

Comment: My foot hurts when I drop a hammer on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant either this:

```
var options = {
  'https.globalAgent.options.ca': [fs.readFileSync('')]
};
```

Or this:

```
var options = {
  https: {
    globalAgent: {
      options: {
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('')]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

or you probably meant this:

```
var options = {};

options[https.globalAgent.options.ca] = [fs.readFileSync('')];
```